# how to add a pyside QGraphicsScene to a BoxLayout

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a `PySide2.QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout` and a `PySide2.QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene` and I want to put the `GraphicsScene` in the layout. Here's a part of my code:

```
self.cn_graph = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
[...]
self.ly_bottom = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
[...]
self.ly_bottom.addWidget(self.cn_graph)
```

but I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(QGraphicsScene)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget, int = 0,         
  PySide2.QtCore.Qt.Alignment = Default(Qt.Alignment))
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget)
```

I don't know if it's even possible to have a `graphicsscene` in a `boxlayout` so any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGraphicsScene is not a widget, it is not a visual element, but a paint handler, instead you should use the QGraphicsView:

```
self.cn_scene_graph = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
self.cn_view_graph = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.cn_scene_graph)
# ...
self.ly_bottom = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
# ...
self.ly_bottom.addWidget(self.cn_view_graph)
```